# How to display twitter feeds in webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I want to display the [URL](https://twitter.com/ncbn) in WebView ,Could ant one help?

I have tried but not getting:

WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

```
wv.loadUrl("URL");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the  tag element in your layout activity . Like This is  a layout file in which the WebView show on the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

and after load the WebView with loadUrl() method like,

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("URL");

and your application must have access to the Internet in manifest  file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable javascript for the WebView. This is disabled by default.

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```